# Can I make a Spring RabbitListener alias?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have `@RabbitListener(id="example", queues={"a", "b"})` listener which I copy pasted on multiple locations in my code throughout different modules. I wanted to create an alias such as:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MessageMapping
@Documented
public @interface MyRabbitListener {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String id() default "example";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String containerFactory() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String[] queues() default {"a", "b"};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    boolean exclusive() default false;

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String priority() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String admin() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    QueueBinding[] bindings() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String group() default "";
}
```

And then I simply use `@MyRabbitListener` on my methods but it doesn't work since I guess there is not alias support for `spring-amqp` module yet. Is there any way I can register my alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I made a dumb mistake and didn't create alias correctly. It should look like this:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MessageMapping
@Documented
@RabbitListener(id = "example", queues = {"a", "b"})
public @interface MyRabbitListener {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String containerFactory() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    boolean exclusive() default false;

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String priority() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String admin() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    QueueBinding[] bindings() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String group() default "";
}
```